# Computer freezes with Visual Artifacts/Scrambled Screen (even at BIOS)

Tags: bios, freeze, visual-artifacts

System Specs:

> **Motherboard:** [Gigabyte GA-G31M-S2l](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2693#ov) (BIOS f8b - stock)[1](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2693#ov)
>   **Processor:** [Intel Core 2 DUO](http://ark.intel.com/products/36500/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7400-%283M-Cache-2_80-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB%29)  - stock cooler
>   **PSU       :** [CoolerMaster eXtreme Power Plus 460W](http://www.coolermaster.in/product.php?product_id=3686)
>   **HDD:** 1 x 640 GB SATA, 1 x 320 GB IDE
>   **RAM:** 2 x 2GB  DDR2
>   **GPU:** OnBoard

Everything is on stock.

---

The artifacts/Scrambelled screen comes up anytime after boot. even when I am in BIOS Settings.

I have the following sensors that monitor temperature

> **CPU :** 35
>   **CORE #1:** 50
>   **CORE #2:** 50
>
> **HDD1:** 39  HDD2: 36

---

What could possibly cause this issue ?

- Can this be because of a underpowerd system? I had once given My PSU for RMA(and they gave me a repaired one after a week and from its serial no I can tell that the one they returned wasn't mine) so I doubt its output.
- or **<strike>can it be because of high CPU temperature</strike>**? I had this problem when I just turned on the PC with CPU at 46 C

---

I have tried :-

- testing one memory stick at a time as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/82504/computer-freezes-navigating-bios) but that
  doesn't help..
- Cleaning the dust on the board and CPU fan (without removing it)
- reducing the HW to minimum
- memtest86+ v2.6 - completed without any error temperature of CPU just after memtest was 65 C
- reassembling the system.

But none of them helped..

---

- Updating drivers is not an option as this thing comes up before
  booting into OS.
- BIOS version is f8b(stock) I haven't added any HW and the system was
  running fine for the past 3 years.

---

[image: Scrambled screen]

Comment: how long does it take the screen to freeze? since you can pass memtest this seems to be somewhat random.

Comment: the first time this happened my system was running for more thatn 24 hours.. But then next day it happened immediately after turning on the system..

Comment: I am now running memtest gain in the usual position of my CPU case.. last time my case was lying horizontally allowing more air to flow in than usual..

Comment: Just curious, is it words getting messed up or colours? 46 degrees is normalish - my systems run at that most of the time. PSU seems sufficient for the specs.

Comment: I just added a snap of the screen have a look..

Comment: are you speaking about scrambled text on screen right at BIOS?

it had happened with me. and i got past it after just taking out and cleaning my RAM sticks.

if you have another working PC, try using RAM stick from that machine...

Comment: Yes.. I also suspected a bad RAM at first but I checked the system with one stick at a time and that didn't work... Memtest86+ also didn't give any error.. I'll try testing RAM on a friends PC and get back here..

Comment: What is your GPU? If you are not using the inbuilt one, try using it to see if it is the GPU's fault.

Comment: GPU is onboard :|

Answer (score 0):

You have a hardware problem. It is either that you have a loose/broken cable somewhere, your graphics capabilities have been messed with, or you have a defective screen. My bet would be the middle one.

Comment: I just reassembled the system and I am testing it now.. If the screen/VGA cable isn't defective as the computer freezes along with the scrambled output..

Answer (score 0):

At first look, I did fix a similar problem several years ago, related to graphic card, with DAC damaged. Try to use the graphic card (and RAM memory by the way) on another computer and search for the same problem. If your graphic card is integrated, try to borrow a PCIexpress graphic card and try with it, using the graphic card port of the new card. This problem is highly hardware related, and perhaps you need certain components for make tests, something new but easy to learn for the novice.